# Getting generic value from fieldinfo throws exception: "Late bounds operation cannot be performed..."

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to get an instance value of a generic type from a static field inside a generic class, and it throws this exception:

> **Late bound operations cannot be performed on fields with types for which Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true**

```
public class ManagerTemplate<Q, T> : IObjectManager
        where T : Filmation.Runtime.Engine.ObjectId, new( )
        where Q : ManagerTemplate<Q, T>, new( ) {

        public readonly static Q Instance = new Q( );         <---- STATIC FIELD
}


private static void FindManagers( ) {
    var IObjectManagerType = typeof( IObjectManager );

    var managers = IObjectManagerType.Assembly
          .GetTypes( )
          .Where( t => !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any( i => i == IObjectManagerType) );

    foreach (var manager in managers) {
         var fi = manager.GetField( "Instance" );
         var instance = fi.GetValue( null );                  <--- EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

I have tried to use GetGenericTypeDefinition, but continues throwing the exception.

I have searched in google, but I have not found how it can be done...

Anyone knows how it can be done?

EDIT: The same using a static property

This is the workaround that I have implemented, (though I'd like to know if it can be done using reflection):

```
public static Q Instance { get; private set; }

static ManagerTemplate( ) {
     Instance = new Q( );
     Environment.Managers.Add( Instance );
}
```

Comment: I like what you are trying to do there by using reflection. You just define the "Manager" in the generic parameter types and now you know who all the managers are automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the value of `public readonly static Q Instance = new Q( );` from the *Generic Type Definition* `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>`, simply because there is no concrete type for `Q`.

How do you get an instance of the generic type definition `Q` if you do not *yet* know what the *concrete* type for `Q` is? Simple: You can't.

Now... if what you want to get is an instance of a type that descends from `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>` where the generic type parameter `Q` is defined, then you actually want to exclude Generic Type Parameters from your search.

```
private static IEnumerable<IObjectManager> FindManagers()
{
  Type type = typeof(IObjectManager);
  IEnumerable<Type> managers = type.Assembly
                   .GetTypes()
                   .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(type));

  foreach (Type manager in managers)
  {
    var fi = manager.GetField("Instance", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    if (fi != null && 
       !fi.FieldType.IsGenericParameter && 
        type.IsAssignableFrom(fi.FieldType))
    {
      yield return (IObjectManager) fi.GetValue(null);
    }
  }
}
```

This will get you all the "Managers" defined in all classes that descend from `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>` that have defined what the type `Q` is.

Comment: You might want to add a null check for `fi` because not all implementors of `IObjectManager` necessarily are descendants of `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>`

Comment: Is just added. Thanks for your answer, I didn't realize that I got types with unresolved generic types.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to get the Instance field from an *unbound generic type*, that is, a generic type with unspecified type arguments.  An unbound type cannot be instantiated or its methods be called. You need a bound generic type with all the type parameters specified, but consider that each different concrete bound type won't share static fields. For example `ManagerTemplate<Class1, Class2>` will return a different Instance that `ManagerTemplate<Class1, Class3>`. All instances of `ManagerTemplate<Class1, Class2>` will share static fields, though.

You can use reflection to bind type arguments to unspecified type parameters of unbound generic types with `Type.MakeGenericType`. You will need to provide type arguments to your FindManagers class:

```
private static void FindManagers<Q,T>( ) {
    var IObjectManagerType = typeof( IObjectManager );

    var managers = IObjectManagerType.Assembly
          .GetTypes( )
          .Where( t => !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any( i => i == IObjectManagerType) );

    foreach (var manager in managers) {
         var concreteType = manager.MakeGenericType(typeof(Q), typeof(T));
         var fi = concreteType.GetField( "Instance" );
         var instance = fi.GetValue( null );                
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you simply want *all* managers? Which is what OP wants, according to the intention expressed by his code example.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve the problem like the following way. Let's start from the code, and I will then explain *why the code*:

```
public interface IObjectManager {
}

public abstract class ObjectManager: IObjectManager {
    static IEnumerable<IObjectManager> ManagerInstancesIterator() {
        foreach(var managerType in managerTypes) {
            var info=managerType.BaseType.GetField("Instance");
            var instance=info.GetValue(null) as IObjectManager;
            yield return instance;
        }
    }

    public static IObjectManager[] FindManagerInstances() {
        return ManagerInstancesIterator().ToArray();
    }

    public ObjectManager() {
        managerTypes.Add(this.GetType());
    }

    static readonly HashSet<Type> managerTypes=new HashSet<Type>();
}

public class ManagerTemplate<Q, T>: ObjectManager
    where T: new()
    where Q: ManagerTemplate<Q, T>, new() {
    public readonly static Q Instance=new Q();
}

public class CuriousClass<T>
    : ManagerTemplate<CuriousClass<T>, T> where T: new() {
}
```

the test code:

```
public static partial class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        var instanceByObject=CuriousClass<object>.Instance;
        var instanceByInt32=CuriousClass<int>.Instance;

        var instances=ObjectManager.FindManagerInstances();
    }
}
```

Note the constraint of `Filmation.Runtime.Engine.ObjectId` is removed temporarily, you can add it back as your requirement.

You are using the *curiously recurring template pattern*, and the consumers' code in fact does not have a way to instantiate `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>` without implementing a concrete class which inherits from `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>`.

For the reason you encountered the exception, is pointed out by other answers. The class `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>` is an open generic class, that is, unless you specified the type arguments, the generic class is just a *definition*; it doesn't have a type instance.

The *close generic type* would be in the runtime types cache, and doesn't exist in the assembly. So the easiest way to get the type instances which are really used to instantiate objects, is store them in a collection. But as `ManagerTemplate<Q, T>` is generic, if we declare a collection in its class declaration, then there would be different collections for each close generic type. This is the reason why a base class `ObjectManager`. But, we don't want itself be instantiated, so it's abstract.

For why `managerTypes.Add(this.GetType());` is in an instance constructor instead of a class initializer, the reason is simple, a static constructor doesn't let us know what type is *this*.

So in conclution, I consider a design in this way as a practical solution.

Comment: Is similar to the workaround I used..  I didn't know the pattern name, and I like the curiousclass... :) thx for explanation ... +1